# Auto-date pasted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with auto-dating cells.  The code below works fine if enter is pressed on only 1 cell.  What I would like to do is auto-date a number of rows that is pasted into the cells (this could be any number).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A100001")) Is Nothing Then
            With Target(1, 2)
                .Value = Date
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

Again, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do what you need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A100001")) Is Nothing Then
        'iterate through all cells in Target range
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next cell
        Target.Columns.Offset(0, 1).AutoFit
    End If
End Sub
```

This will iterate through all of the cells in the Target range (everything that was just changed with your paste) and add the date into the next column. We determine the next column using .offset(0,1). After it's done iterating we call the `.autofit` on the next column.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A100001"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In rng
        With r(1, 2)
            .Value = Date
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```